# using transform twice in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transforms

I have used

```
$(".container").css("transform", "translate3d(450px,0,0)")
```

in my jQuery code in the beginning (in line 10). Now I have to add scale to my container so I added following line in my code

`$(".container").css("transform", "scale(1.5)")`

But now it rewrites my previous transformation wiz translate3d I want to add scale along with translate. How do I do it ?

**NOTE:** First transformation and second transformation are in completely different blocks. so

`$(".container").css("transform", "translate3d(450px,0,0) scale(1.5)")`

wont work.

**UPDATE**

I tried saving the current transformation in a variable and then adding the new transformation, like below

```
container.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var currentTransform = $(this).css("transform");
        $(this).css("transform", currentTransform + "scale(1.5)")
    }
    , mouseleave: function () {
        var currentTransform = $(this).css("transform");
        $(this).css("transform", currentTransform + "scale(1.0)")
    }
});
```

but now on mouseleave scale doesn't change. It doesn't come back to its original shape.

***A note***

when I executed `console.log(currentTransform)` It gave transform information in a matrix form. I still don't get how to remove this bug. Please help.

Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be the correct method but it worked fine for me.

```
events.on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        var currentTransform = $(this).css("transform");
        $(this).css("transform", currentTransform + "scale(1.5)")
    }
    , mouseleave: function () {
        var currentTransform = $(this).css("transform");
        var str = currentTransform.split(",")
        str[0] = "matrix(1"
        str[3] = "1"
        $(this).css("transform", str)
    }
});
```

In this modification, I split the current string at commas and then I modified those parts which are related to the scale.